# What distribution corresponds to the asymmetric Around?

Tags: distributions

The documentation for Around, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html, indicates that

> For linear computations, Around[x,δ] behaves like a number whose values are distributed according to the normal distribution NormalDistribution[x,δ].

But what distribution is used for the asymmetric Around[x,{δ-,δ+}]? Is it SkewNormalDistribution, https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SkewNormalDistribution.html,
and how do I compute the distribution parameters?

Answer (score -3):

No distribution implied.

Its just a notation for a number or a vector with an interval of uncertainity  in experimental measurements. These measurements are influenced by a big number  of noisy impacts, so that in most cases the distibution is normal as the limit of sums of independent variables. The author has to discuss the error influences in order to make the measurments transparent to th reader. But in most cases a look to the histogram suffices to identify a normal distribution or distortions.

Its background idea is the law of error propagation, that is based on differentials of functions of  $t$ and the the Wiener process $W(t).

$$ d f(t, W(t)) = \partial_t f(t, W(t)) \ dt + \partial_W f(t,W(t)) \ dW(t)+ 1/2 \ \partial_{W,W} f(t,W(t)) dW(t)^2 (= dt) $$

To get it working, simply try all formulae

```
     Around[a,{-b,c}] + Around[d,{-e,f}]
     Subsuperscript[a+d, -Sqrt[b^2+e^2], +Sqrt[c^2+f^2]]

     Around[x,{-a,b}] Around[y,{-c,d}]
     Subsuperscript[x y, -Sqrt[c^2 x^2+a^2 y^2], 
                         +Sqrt[d^2 ^2+b^2 y^2]]
```

As intended, both error intervals add by square roots of sums of squares, positive and negative separately. It looks more like a practical error propagation law for the first three moments, not so much as the implication, that its a distorted Gaussian with all higher moments determined by the first moments.

Comment: Are you a bot or you just keep posting nonsensical chatGPT-generated answers for whatever reason?

Comment: Are you a bot commenting on everything you dont understand?